# grabcut image segmentation in android

Tags: android

I am trying to run this code that I found from the net:

```
package com.opencv.grabcut.android;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.opencv.android.Utils;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat; 
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class Grabcut extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
    ImageView imageView;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    Canvas canvas;
    Scalar color = new Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255);
    Point tl, br;
    int counter;
    Bitmap bitmapResult, bitmapBackground;
    Mat dst = new Mat();
    final String pathToImage  = "/mnt/sdcard/gcut.png";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.grabcut_main);
        imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathToImage);
        Toast msg = Toast.makeText(Grabcut.this, "Press top left and bottom right of the      foreground image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        msg.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, 0, 0);

        msg.show();
        bitmapResult = bitmap.copy(bitmap.getConfig(), true);
        canvas = new Canvas(bitmapResult);

        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapResult);
        imageView.setOnTouchListener(this);

        tl = new Point();
        br = new Point();
        counter = 0;
    }

  //@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (counter == 0) {
                tl.x = event.getX();
                tl.y = event.getY();
                counter++;
            } else if (counter == 1) {
                br.x = event.getX();
                br.y = event.getY();
                counter++;

                Mat img = new Mat();
                img = Highgui.imread(pathToImage);
                Mat background = new Mat();
                try {
                    background = Utils.loadResource(getApplicationContext(),
                            R.drawable.wall );
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                backgroundSubtracting(img, background);
                Highgui.imwrite("/mnt/sdcard/GRABCUT/rect.png", dst);
                Bitmap jpg = BitmapFactory
                         .decodeFile("/mnt/sdcard/GRABCUT/rect.png");

                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
                imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                imageView.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(jpg);
                imageView.invalidate();
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void backgroundSubtracting(Mat img, Mat background) {
        Mat firstMask = new Mat();
        Mat bgModel = new Mat();
        Mat fgModel = new Mat();
        Mat mask;
        Mat source = new Mat(1, 1, CvType.CV_8U, new Scalar(3.0));
        dst = new Mat();
        Rect rect = new Rect(tl, br);

        Imgproc.grabCut(img, firstMask, rect, bgModel, fgModel, 1, 0 /* GC_INIT_WITH_RECT */);
        Core.compare(firstMask, source/* GC_PR_FGD */, firstMask, Core.CMP_EQ);

        Mat foreground = new Mat(img.size(), CvType.CV_8UC3, new Scalar(255,
                255, 255));
        img.copyTo(foreground, firstMask);

        Core.rectangle(img, tl, br, color);

            Mat tmp = new Mat();
            Imgproc.resize(background, tmp, img.size());
            background = tmp;
            mask = new Mat(foreground.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1, new Scalar(255, 255, 255));

        Imgproc.cvtColor(foreground, mask, 6/* COLOR_BGR2GRAY */);
        Imgproc.threshold(mask, mask, 254, 255, 1 /* THRESH_BINARY_INV */);

        Mat vals = new Mat(1, 1, CvType.CV_8UC3, new Scalar(0.0));
        background.copyTo(dst);

        background.setTo(vals, mask);
        enter code here
        Core.add(background, foreground, dst, mask);

        firstMask.release();
        source.release();
        bgModel.release();
        fgModel.release();
        vals.release();
    }

}
```

There is one error that i don't understand in there
the error goes like this: "wall cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Pardone me if did not explain it clearly, I quite new on android development...

please help.. thanks :)

Comment: You are missing wall.jpg in to your drawable folder. You can use other image resource instead of the wall.

Comment: I can't find this tutorial online, can you link me to it?

Answer (score 0):

Copy an image file with file name as "wall.png" under /res/drawable/.
That is suppose to fix the error.